# Is There A Way To Allow Permanent Admin Rights To An Application In Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, administrator, privileges

I usually rar/zip files with Winrar, but today when i was archiving files on drive C:/ got this message:

[image]

I suppose this is because the application does not have sufficient rights to rar/zip files/folders on drive C:/

I however succeeded only when launched Winrar with admin rights, however it defeats the purpose of archiving with context menu.

Is there a way to give Winrar permanent admin rights?

**Please note:** I have censored filename on picture.

Comment: I removed the winrar tag since the question holds for any windows application

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried this?

1. Right-click the application, and then click Properties.
2. Click the Compatibility tab.
3. Select the Run this program as an administrator checkbox, and then click OK.

Comment: Strange, but this does not work well as it seems. Checkbox is checked but Winrar still asks for a permission to run from "Unknown Publisher". Winrar's icon has that "shield icon" by the way.

Comment: I think it works only when directly running Winrar but when launching downloaded archived file from browser like Chrome, it executes associated program which is Winrar but not with admin rights enabled for it. I wonder how to make browser execute downloaded archive file with Winrar already with enabled admin rights.

Comment: This worked for my efforts to start WinRAR from the context menu with admin rights. Win10 will popup a request for admin rights to be allowed each usage, so it's good to set for batch work I need to do, and disable after. (For anyone stumbling upon this exact WinRAR issue, it solved the ability to archive old hard disc drives that require admin privileges to access all files and folders.)