# WinRAR: Access is Denied when archiving

Tags: windows-7, winrar

I am trying to backup an old drive from a WinXP machine in Windows 7 using WinRAR.  I keep getting "Access is Denied" in a lot of the folders I'm trying to include.  I don't really want to go changing file permissions on the drive.  Is there a way to get WinRAR to ignore file permissions?

Answer (score 7):

When you open WinRar make sure you right click and select "Run As Administrator". even though you are a administrator user programs you run will not have administrator privileges unless you do that.

If the files are still not readable that means either the file is in use and has a exclusive lock, or that the administrator does not have permissions to read. One thing I would recommend is use [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/) to copy the file before you try coying it. I have used it to copy files that are being difficult. It will elevate itself to administrator privileges if it needs to.

Comment: The problem I'm having is that when using Explorer's right-click context menu to "add to archive" -- you know, the most convenient method -- it's not running as administrator so it can't create the archive.  I wish there was a way to have such commands request elevation automatically instead of just throwing an error and giving up.

Comment: @Triynko, same issue for me. The solution here worked: https://superuser.com/questions/331383/is-there-a-way-to-allow-permanent-admin-rights-to-an-application-in-windows-7

Answer (score 0):

If your OS is preventing you from having access, and you're in an administrator account, the folders are likely limited to the SYSTEM user, which is a user you can never log into or run applications at. As such, WinRAR will never be able to side-step such things.

What you may want to consider instead is booting into a LiveCD environment, such as Ubuntu or OpenSUSE. Ironically enough, I find that the LiveCD environments have better access to NTFS partitions for XP, Vista, and especially Windows 7. If you want to side-step the permissions and archive large folders, this is the way to do it.

I find that in Windows 7, copying profiles and other things with "limited access" or require administrative access to authorize copy, are really crummy in terms of copying performance, and accurate feedback of progress. This is specifically when doing it in Windows 7. Doing the same thing, on the same folders in a LiveCD environment not only provides you with proper performance, but also proper progress feedback.

Go Microsoft on your awesome implementation of your own format technology.

Comment: Only reason is that linux does not respect window's permission as expect where Windows 7 will respect Windows XP file structure and the ownership of said files as expected.

Comment: at least Windows is better than OSX/BSD that copies folders by replacing them rather than appending them. You can take ownership or add privies to those folders , but then these are usually temp or cached files , so why are they important?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [Robocopy](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) with the /B switch to ignore the file permissions and copy the files to your backup drive. You'll need to run Robocopy with an administrator/elevated command prompt for this to work.

It won't compress the files of course, but you can always do that after copying the files and stripping the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the archive, Properties then, in the attributes deselect "read-only".

Comment: OP said he doesn't want to change the file permissions. Did you read the entire question?

Answer (score 0):

I came here with the same problem.. suddenly I got an idea in my head... this is how I fixed it. I have the folder excluded in my File System Shield on Avast, I disabled that temporarily, and I could extract it. Don't know if it was the solution but could be.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little necroposting.

If you use rar.exe (command line versione of WinRar) you've got a -dh flag that let you archive files in use by other programs (at your own risk).

You've got a similar option in WinRar backup options (open shared files) and you can of course create a custom profile with this option enabled.